# Get socket handshake data before proxying websocket request in nodejs via http-proxy

Tags: node.js, socket.io, http-proxy

I want to access the handshake data that `socket.io` client has sent along with the handshake request:

```
socket=io(origin, {
   transport:["polling", "websocket"],
   auth: {
     token: 'abcd',
     id: 'someid', 
  } 
});
```

Now in http-proxy, I want to access this data before proxying the request to the target. How can I achieve this? I have to access the user information before the upgrade and at arrival of handshake data.

```
server.on('upgrade', function (req, socket, head) {
   // access auth data here
    proxy.ws(req, socket, head);
});
```